TinyMCE 7 Toolbar focus and hover state color... change from vivid blue?
Title says it all really.  TinyMCE 7 has changed the hover colour for buttons and menus to a vivid blue.  How can I change it to another colour, or back to the way it was pre TinyMCE 7?
